# Extjs - Cannot hide window

Tags: extjs

I'm using Extjs 4.2 and I got a problem.

I created an object "Window_Graph" wich extends "Window". When I try to hide this object, it makes a javascript error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined".

There is my object :

```
Ext.define('PFS.view.Window_Graph', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    alias: 'widget.window_graph',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    closable: true,
    header: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    border: false,
    tbar: [
        { xtype: 'button', action: 'modifier',       text: 'Modifier',       iconCls: 'iconAppEdit'     },
        { xtype: 'button', action: 'deplacer',       text: 'Déplacer',       iconCls: 'iconArrowOut'    },
        { xtype: 'button', action: 'redimensionner', text: 'Redimensionner', iconCls: 'iconShapeHandles'},
        { xtype: 'button', action: 'supprimer',      text: 'Supprimer',      iconCls: 'iconCross'       },
    ],
    autoShow: true,
    constrain: true
});
```

There is when I create my window_graph :

```
Ext.getCmp('page1').add({
    xtype:    'window_graph',
    id:       'graph_1',
    width:    500,
    height:   300,
    x:        10,
    y:        10
});
```

And next, I try to hide it like that :

```
Ext.getCmp('graph_1').hide();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code where you have your instance that you are trying to hide?

Comment: There must be something else in there causing problems, I tried the code in my next comment at this page and did not have any issues: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/docs/Ext.window.Window.1/viewer.html Do you see differences in what I have vs what you have?

Comment: Code I tried:
`Ext.onReady(function () {
  Ext.define('PFS.view.Window_Graph', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    alias: 'widget.window_graph',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    closable: true,
    header: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    border: false,
    tbar: [{xtype: 'button',text: 'Modifier'}],
    autoShow: true,
    constrain: true
  });
  
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', { id: 'myPanel', title: 'Test Panel', renderTo: Ext.getBody() });
  Ext.getCmp('myPanel').add({xtype: 'window_graph', id:'myWin'});
  Ext.getCmp('myWin').hide()
});`

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues either: http://jsfiddle.net/n3g4U/1/

Comment: I found the problem. It's because in an other Controller, I had this line `'window_graph': { beforehide:  this.windowGraph_BHide }` and I didn't define `windowGraph_BHide` in the controller. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Ext.getCmp** is returing **undefined** in your case!
This is what the error message is telling you.

I think I know the reason why you are getting this.
The initialization process isn't finished yet. You are calling `Ext.getCmp("graph_1")` too early. If you want to hide the window upon creation use `autoShow=false`.

Alternatively you can also try this

```
var graphWindow = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("window_graph")[0];
debugger; //look in the console if you are getting an object back.
graphWindow.hide();
```